# file upload issue using FormatData in IE (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, form-data

I have a post request which uploads file along with some other basic information. It works fine in chrome browser but it is inconsistent in IE. Some times file is uploaded(file + some additional info) but mostly it fails in IE. I tracked the post request in Fiddler and the textview tab was empty for that request. The request was not complete. The error code was 408.I also got a popup message from fiddler : "content length mismatch: Expecting content of 3213 but client send 0". Hence, the request itself was not complete.

Below give is code for formation of fomrdata and post request

```
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        formData.append("info1", info1);
        formData.append("info2", info2);
        formData.append("info3", info3);
        formData.append("info4", info4);
        var defer = $q.defer();
        return $http.post(url, formData,
        {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        });
```

Please suggest me some solution to this problem.An alternative solution will also work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with angular and FormData. In my case, in Chrome, everything works fine - In IE 11.20.10586 on my Windows 10 computer, also no problem - But with IE 11.0.9600.18059 (Windows 7) and IE 11.0.9600.17728 (Windows Server), impossible to send a file, IE hangs.

Reading [this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/813443/uploading-empty-file-ie10-ie11-hangs-indefinitely), it seems to be an IE bug. I was unable to fix it, but found a workaround that worked: posting the form twice, the first time without any file. Try something like that:

```
var formData = new FormData();
$http.post(url, formData,
    {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).success(function(){
        formData.append("file", file);
        formData.append("info1", info1);
        formData.append("info2", info2);
        formData.append("info3", info3);
        formData.append("info4", info4);
        $http.post(url, formData,
        {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        });
    });
```